# Slideshow stop working after adding second slide show

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem with my webpage.
My first slideshow is stuck on the 2nd image after adding the 2nd slideshow on the webpage.
The 1st one was working perfectly.
[image]

The left one(1st slideshow) is stuck on the second image, while the right one(2nd slideshow) is working perfectly. I have checked the code and can't find anything wrong with it.

Below is my code:

//Style

```
<style>
 .Slides1, Slides2{
 display: none;
 }

 img {vertical-align: middle;}

 .slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  }

  .dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  }

  .active {
  background-color: #717171;
  }

  /* Fading animation */
  .fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
  }

  @keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
  }
  </style>
```

//Slideshow 1

```
<!-- Slideshow1 -->
  <div style="display: table-cell; background-color:white">
  <div class="slideshow-container" style="padding-left:120px">

  <div class="Slides1 fade">
  <img src="1.jpg" style="width:65%;">
  <br>
  Home Theatre Systems
  </div>
  <div class="Slides1 fade">  
  <img src="1.2.jpg" style="width:65%">
  <br>
  Automatic Hygiene System
  </div>
  <div class="Slides1 fade">  
  <img src="1.3.jpg" style="width:65%">
  <br>
  Computer Peripherals
  </div>
  <div class="Slides1 fade">  
  <img src="1.4.jpg" style="width:65%">
  <br>
  High End Radio Controlled Products
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
```

//JavaScript 1

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("Slides1");
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
     slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(showSlides, 2500); 

  }
 </script>
```

//Slideshow2

```
<!-- Slideshow2 -->
  <div style="display: table-cell; background-color:#AED6F1">
  <div class="slideshow-container" style="padding-left:120px">

  <div class="Slides2 fade">
  <img src="2.1.jpg" style="width:65%;">
  <br>
  Home Theatre Systems
  </div>
  <div class="Slides2 fade">  
  <img src="2.2.jpg" style="width:65%">
  <br>
  Automatic Hygiene System
  </div>
  <div class="Slides2 fade">  
  <img src="2.3.jpg" style="width:65%">
  <br>
  Computer Peripherals
  </div>
  <div class="Slides2 fade">  
  <img src="2.4.jpg" style="width:65%">
  <br>
  High End Radio Controlled Products
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ------------------------------------------------------------------ -->
```

//JavaScript 2

```
<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
var i;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("Slides2");
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
     slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
setTimeout(showSlides, 2500); 

  }
</script>
```

Comment: `slideIndex` and `showSlides` in javascript2 "replaces" `slideIndex` and `showSlides` in javascript 1 - i.e. you can't have the same variable/function name twice and expect both to exist :p - simple solution, wrap **all the code** in each of javascript1 and javascript2 in an IIFE ... `(function() { .... the code goes here ... })();`

Comment: Ai, silly me. Got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to change slideIndex and showSlides to a different name for the 2nd slideshow